# css column-count with vendor prefixes causes issues with Less and Grunt

Tags: css, less, gruntjs, vendor-prefix

When I have

```
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
```

in my less files Grunt would die

```
Running "recess:bootstrap" (recess) task
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

It appears the dashes are causing problems. Am I doing it wrong?

PS: I'm working on a Bootstrap fork.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting.  I don't think it's a vendor prefix, but it is easily reproducable with column-count.  I tried some other styles and didn't encounter the issue.

If you simply put the -webkit-column-count before the -moz-column-count, it works, but I'm not sure why.

```
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
```

Comment: Updated my title. Thanks! It's a fix but I'm curious why it isn't working in the other order.

Comment: It works fine in recess, so it's evidently an issue/bug with grunt-recess.  Maybe you should file an issue.  :)